# Create date column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, analysis, prediction, forecasting

i obtained data in RDBMS with SQL and want to forecast the daily purchase using R.

Here is the first 12 rows of the data . 
[image: first 12 data]

What i want to make is store the dataframe like in the image below, and in the end i will try to write function to Forecast it by each item title which is in the rows using exponential smoothing.
[image: Purpose of dataframe]

So far, i have succesfully done the title column. But i cannot make multiple date column exactly like the 2nd image above. Here is the code so far :

```
df1 <- data.frame() 
dailydate <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(data$date_placed))
newdate <- unique(dailydate)
itemtitle <- as.character(data$title)
newitemtitle <- unique(itemtitle)
df1 <- data.frame(newitemtitle,t(dailydate))
Error in data.frame(newitemtitle, t(dailydate))
```

I cannot add new column into `df1` ,and also not yet find the way to match the daily quantity based on the title. I am open to any suggestion with this problem

Comment: Try to give us the sample of your data using `dput` rather than the picture.

Comment: @user2100721 yes, i have recently read about it and update the result, is that one right?

Comment: If you have a new question- please post it as one. Keeping piling up edits on the original question and hence both invalidating the answer and keeping holding the answers as your hostages is not hos SO works

Comment: @DavidArenburg oh, yes. thanks for the suggestion,i'll fix my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to use the `reshape2` package.

```
df1 <- structure(list(title = structure(c(5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("d", "k", "m", "n", "q", "t", "u", "v"
), class = "factor"), quantity = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 13L, 
4L, 6L, 12L, 1L), date_placed = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("8/24/2013", "8/25/2013", "8/26/2013", 
"8/27/2013", "8/28/2013"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("title", 
"quantity", "date_placed"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#install.packages("reshape2")
reshape2:::dcast(df1, title ~ date_placed, value.var = "quantity", fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
#  title 8/24/2013 8/25/2013 8/26/2013 8/27/2013 8/28/2013
#1     d         0        10         4         0         0
#2     k         0         0        13         0         0
#3     m         3         0         0         0         1
#4     n         0         0         0         6         0
#5     q         4         0         0         0         0
#6     t         5         0         0         0         0
#7     u         0         6         0         0         0
#8     v         0         0         0         0        12
```

The benefit of this over the other answer is that the output is a data.frame that can now be manipulated as you wish, instead of a table.

Comment: thanks for the library @Chrisss , i have used the ``reshape2`` package using ``dcast`` and ``melt`` function. However, there is one more obstacle. Now i have 3 columns (``title``,``quantity``,``date_placed``) where titles are duplicated but with different ``date_placed`` and ``quantity`` . How am i possible to do forecast with duplicated ``title`` rows ?

Comment: You should really use `dput()` on your data to help us reproduce your problem if you want a more detailed solution. As of now, I don't understand the problem. `dcast` is making a wide data.frame with the unique values of `title` as rows and the unique values of `date_placed` as the columns and the cells are populated by `quantity`. `title` should not be duplicated anywhere in the final data.frame

Comment: yes,i have recently use `dput()` for R, and have trouble in forecasting the `unique` title value

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, date_placed, quantity, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to transform your data

```
xtabs(data = df1,quantity~title+date_placed)
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(title = structure(c(5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("d", "k", "m", "n", "q", "t", "u", "v"
), class = "factor"), quantity = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 13L, 
4L, 6L, 12L, 1L), date_placed = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("8/24/2013", "8/25/2013", "8/26/2013", 
"8/27/2013", "8/28/2013"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("title", 
"quantity", "date_placed"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```